# is life insurance halal in Islam which is based on Takaful method?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam

I know normal life insurance is Haram (forbidden) which is provided by traditional interest/Riba/gambling based banking company.

But if life insurance provided by any Islamic bank then will it be halal where there is not interest/riba in it?

I found most of the Islamic life insurance company run based on **Takaful method (which means may be mutual risk sharing or guaranty to each other)**. those type of insurance provider are saying its Islamic shariah compliant.

But i am confused because i found on internet any kind of life insurance is **haram because of uncertainty or try to ensure something(specially life or my family after life) by the help anything other than Allah (or something like that) (where Allah is the one who can ensure anything and who know the future and who provide the living/riz'k and to whom only we need to rely on)**

So can anyone please tell me about it in **details(including the openion about Takaful method)** with authentic opinion(from Quran, Sahih Hadith, Islamic Research, opinion of well know Arab Sheikh or expert in related field etc.)

jazakallah khairan

Answer (score -1):

When you have Life Isurnace you have to pay the company about each month. As long as this money is not haraam that you are paying, you will not get haraam money in return from the company. Also if interest is included then it is haraam even if you have a halal earning because it is a win/lose situation.

Comment: what about risk or uncertainty of life insurance if people die? and relying issue only to Allah etc. please provide any authentic document or research paper or opinion of well know scholar.

Comment: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1129/why-is-life-insurance-considered-un-islamic

Comment: http://www.islamhelpline.net/node/371

Comment: your first link seems telling that its haram. do you also mean it haram? or you told halal? may be i misunderstood. please explain a bit more.